# How to transition to a new viewController after Firebase Authentication?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have successfully implemented Firebase pre-built UI. It includes providers for google, facebook, email, and phone. Launching the app brings you to a viewController with a login button. Clicking the button brings up the `authUIController`. After signing in to one of the providers, the `authUIController` disappears and I'm brought back to the original `viewController` with the login button. How do I transition to a new `viewController` after authentication. I am sure its stupid simple and Im over looking something. Please help.

I have tried using `present(viewController(), animation: true, completion: nil)` and `performSegue(withIdentifier: "goHome", sender: nil)` in several different places of my code. I moved my provider's array from `viewDidLoad()` to `viewDidAppear()` and nothing. I don't know what to do here. I have searched Google's documentation, YouTube and stack overflow with no luck. I know that I should only submit snippets of my code, but I am so lost as to what I should show I have pasted the `viewControllers` code.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseUI
import FirebaseDatabase
import FacebookCore
import FacebookLogin
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FacebookShare
import GoogleSignIn

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, FUIAuthDelegate,
GIDSignInUIDelegate, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    @IBAction func loginAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        // Present the default login view controller provided by authUI
        let authViewController = authUI?.authViewController();
        self.present(authViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()

    fileprivate(set) var auth:Auth?
    fileprivate(set) var authUI: FUIAuth? //only set internally but get externally
    fileprivate(set) var authStateListenerHandle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let accessToken = AccessToken.current {
            // User is logged in, use 'accessToken' here.
        }

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()

        self.authStateListenerHandle = self.auth?.addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
            if user != nil {(self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goHome", sender: nil))
            } else {
                self.loginAction(sender: self)
                return
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
            FUIEmailAuth(),
            FUIGoogleAuth(),
            FUIFacebookAuth(),
            FUIPhoneAuth(authUI: FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!),
            ]
        //loginButton.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.auth = Auth.auth()
        self.authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
        self.authUI?.delegate = self
        self.authUI?.providers = providers
    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

        Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                // ...
                return
            }
            // User is signed in
            // ...
        }
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("User Logged Out")
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
        // ...
        if let error = error {
            // ...
            return
        }

        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                       accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                // ...
                return
            }
        }
    }

    // Implement the required protocol method for FIRAuthUIDelegate

    func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: User?, error: Error?) {
        guard let authError = error else { return }

        let errorCode = UInt((authError as NSError).code)

        switch errorCode {
        case FUIAuthErrorCode.userCancelledSignIn.rawValue:
            print("User cancelled sign-in");
            break

        default:
            let detailedError = (authError as NSError).userInfo[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] ?? authError
            print("Login error: \((detailedError as! NSError).localizedDescription)");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe I figured it out! Thanks for everyone's help! Below was the code I had (it was the correct code) but I kept getting an error:    LoginViewController: 0x104f17660> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

```
func viewDidAppear(){
        self.authStateListenerHandle = self.auth?.addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if user != nil {(self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goHome", sender: nil))
        } else {
            self.loginAction(sender: self)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

I kept switching things around and around... the other code I tried was

```
func viewDidAppear(){
        self.authStateListenerHandle = self.auth?.addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if user != nil {(self.present(UIViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil))
        } else {
            self.loginAction(sender: self)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

This code failed no matter what I tried. The first code block was correct, my problem was my storyboard segue was show (push), not present (modally). Once I changed this BAM it worked. Ugh, so simple but crazy to figure out. Again, thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

If your FirebaseUI is being called correctly, you should handle the result in the method called `didSignInWith` like this:

```
func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: FIRUser?, error: Error?) {
  // handle user and error as necessary
}
```

You can check this link to [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui)

Sample:

```
func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: FIRUser?, error: Error?) {
    if error != nil {
        // HANDLE login
        login()
    } else {
        // HANDLE Error
    }
}

func login() {
    let authUI = FIRAuthUI.init(auth: FIRAtuth.auth()!)
    authUI?.delegate = self
    let authViewController = authUI?.authViewController()
    self.present(authViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I used your code, and it didn't work. I changed if error != nil to error == nil and added present(viewController: .... and it send me to a black screen.

Comment: Have you checked if your `user` is not `nil`? Also, this snipped is my code for iOS 9, try look how to present your screen iOS10
Check this [Readme of the Firebase](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-ios/auth/readme.md)`if let authVC = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.authViewController() {  present(authVC, animated: true, completion: nil)  

      }`

Comment: In viewDidLoad() I implemented self.authStateListenerHandle and checked if user != nil performSegue. Maybe the two are conflicting?